# Не подключаются драйверы:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium, gradle, testng

Только начала осваивать автоматизацию тестирования, столкнулась с тем, что Intellij IDEA никак не может подключить geckodriver для Firefox и chromedriver для Chrome.

Выдает ошибку:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more
>   information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html"

Использую:

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.6 (Community Edition)

Build #IC-181.5540.7, built on July 11, 2018

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 7 6.1

TestNG 6.8.17

Selenium 3.13.0

Gradle 4.9

Firefox 50.0.2

Пыталась прописать через вот это, как это рекомендуют на всех форумах в таких случаях:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Путь к geckodriver.exe\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
```

однако IDEA подсвечивает красным setProperty и пишет "Cannot resolve symbol "setProperty", ошибка остается прежней. 
То же самое с geckodriver.

Код записывала Selenium Builder в Firefox, импортировала для TestNG, изначально драйвер прописывался там так:

```
FirefoxDriver wd;
```

Весь код:

```
package FirstOne;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import static org.openqa.selenium.OutputType.*;


public class AmazonLogin {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko/chrome.driver", "Путь к geckodriver.exe\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();


@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    wd = new ChromeDriver();
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void AmazonLogin() {
    wd.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-signin-tooltip']//span[.='Sign in']")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).sendKeys("\\undefined");
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap-credential-autofill-hint")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap-credential-autofill-hint")).sendKeys("\\undefined");
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).clear();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).sendKeys(" /** Mail/ ");
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='a-button-input']")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).sendKeys("\\undefined");
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='authportal-main-section']/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).clear();
    wd.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).sendKeys(" /** Password/ ");
    wd.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit")).click();
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    wd.quit();
}

public static boolean isAlertPresent(ChromeDriver wd) {
    try {
        wd.switchTo().alert();
        return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Что я делаю не так? Уже даже в PATH добавила пути к драйверам.

Comment: Импортируйте System.

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того что не IDEA, а Вы не правильно что-то сделали ибо ошибку выдает Ваш код.

Ну и сама инициализация драйвера не корректная.

У меня такое чудо работает:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Путь к chromedrive.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "/log.log");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");

options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--user-agent="+"юзер агент с браузера"); // Если не надо удалите

options.setCapability("chrome.verbose", true);
options.setCapability("networkConnectionEnabled", true);
options.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
options.setCapability("--user-agent", "юзер агент с браузера");

options.setCapability("browserName", "LinkedinPeopleParser");
options.setCapability("platform", org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, true);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_FINDING_BY_CSS, true);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS, true);

LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.INFO);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.INFO);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.INFO);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.INFO);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.INFO);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.INFO);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

ChromeDriverService driverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingAnyFreePort()
            .usingDriverExecutable(main.getChromeDriverFile())
            .withLogFile(new File("/log.log")).build();

ChromeDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);

... // Ваш код.
```

с Фоксом не работал, не подскажу. Но подозреваю что похоже.

Comment: Код пока просто записанный рекордером, но еще посмотрю, спасибо. 

Можно еще глупый вопрос: это куда именно прописывать? в классе ИДЕА почему-то ругается на setProperty (как писала в посте), подсвечивает красным. С setCapabilitities то же самое. 

Может, есть рекомендации, где посмотреть подробный и понятный туториал по настройке всего этого добра? Пока натыкаюсь либо на уроки, где работают с софтом предыдущих версий, где это было не нужно, либо где это описывается для тех, у кого опыт с джава побольше.

Comment: @Alicefer как раз таки это нужно. Описано на официальных вики selenium и самого chrome driver. на счет того что подсвечивает красным - либо вы заимпортили другие классы с таким же названием или я хз. Как такое может быть, окромя вариантов, не представляю.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решалась крайне просто: нужно было убедиться, что после прописывания зависимостей подгрузились все библиотеки. 
В итоге лично для меня удобнее оказалось работать с maven, и если с ним библиотека не подгрузилась, можно зайти в settings - Build, Execution,Deployment - Build Tools - Maven и поставить галочку в пункте Always update snapshots

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что нельзя в классе просто так вызвать какой либо метод.

```
System.setProperty(...);
```

Вы должны создать метод в котором будет инициализироваться драйвер.

```
public ChromeDriver driver;

public void setDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "PATH TO DRIVER");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sitename пишем свой,
не забываем двойной слеш при прописи пути к драйверу,
а так же качайте версию драйвера такую же, какой у вас хром установлен)

```
package ru.sitename;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class Login {
    @Test
    public void Login() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Autotest\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://dev.sitename.ru/");

    }
```